# End condition for Anagram solver using Arrays: Java

Tags: java, arrays, character

Sorry if this is a bit of a dumb question, but I've been having a bit of a problem with this. The project is a super Anagram solver, which returns true if the letters in the first phrase read from the keyboard are an anagram of some of the letters in the second phrase read from the keyboard. My idea for the algorithm was to convert the strings to arrays, then go down the array for the first string and compare each character with each character down the second array trying to find a match, blanking out that instance of the character if found so it can't be used again. The method would return true if the search for the letter in the second array never failed, but false if a letter couldn't be found. I have no idea how or where to put the return statements for that, though, and I'm drawing a blank.

```
class SuperAnagram {
   public boolean isSuperAnagram(String s, String st){
      s.toLowerCase();
      st.toLowerCase();
      char[] array1 = s.toCharArray();
      char[] array2 = st.toCharArray();
      for(int i = 0;(i<array1.length);i++){
         for(int j = 0;(j<array2.length);j++){
           if (array1[i] == array2[j]){
           array2[j] = ' ';

           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
```

Comment: You're going about it the hard way.  Anagrams boil down to the number of appearances of each character.  You don't need to do any searching, just counting.

Comment: @Kon, you would be right if the OP wanted only to test whether the two strings were anagrams of each other, but what he actually wants is whether the one string is an anagram of *some* (i.e. not necessarily all) of the letters of the other.  It may be that the point of that stipulation is precisely to rule out the solution you suggest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops, didn't read clearly enough. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is one way you could go about it.

You can use a boolean value as a flag:

```
public boolean isSuperAnagram(String s, String st){
    s.toLowerCase();
    st.toLowerCase();
    char[] array1 = s.toCharArray();
    char[] array2 = st.toCharArray();

    boolean myFlag = true; // flag is initially true to enter the loop

    // added another condition to the loop - will exit if myFlag == false
    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length && myFlag; i++){
        myFlag = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
           if (array1[i] == array2[j]){
               array2[j] = ' ';
               myFlag = true;   // found a match, set our flag == true
               // we only want to replace ONE letter, not ALL (so break out of the loop)
               break; 
           }
        }
    }

    // will only return true if every letter in array1 matched some letter in array2
    return myFlag;
}
```

Comment: You understood the question right and this is indeed what I was trying to do, and this works for most of the shorter inputs but for some reason now I'm running into some problems with some of the longer strings. "clinteastwood" and "oldwestaction" should return true, but are instead returning false.

Comment: @RadiumBlue The problem is when you have more than one of the same letter. For instance when you come to the first 't' in "clinteastwood", it's going to turn both 't's in "oldestaction" into spaces instead of the first one it finds. I can update my answer to address this.

Comment: Nevermind, I needed to insert a break after myFlag in the second loop in order to make sure it didn't blank out letters twice in certain instances. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to return value  of boolean . At the end of the if statement 
       return true